# Linking files or folders to another drive

Tags: windows, file, hyperlink, shortcut

I would like to be able to map (or link) one logical folder or file to another on a different harddrive.

I have Virtual Ram HDD and I want to link game files from HDD to RAM ones.

I remember finding a program a couple years back that would trick the system into thinking one folder was really another, but I can't find it. I think it was JumpLink or something.

Anyway, I want to be able to do this:
When the system wants to access 'C:\Game\' it will really access 'X:\Game\' but still think it's on the former drive.

I am not looking to use 'subst' either. I just want to map that folder or and files to the other.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what I was thinking about:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're talking about mounting a file system to a directory on a drive. A quick google search led me to this Server Fault Question: https://serverfault.com/questions/11350/is-it-possible-to-mount-unmount-a-physical-hard-drive-in-windows-xp

To quote Ramon,

> Try mountvol [drive:]path /d. For, info type mountvol /? (just mountvol) in cmd.exe.

See that question for complete details and caveats.